# Show error on auto increment primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to add user address to a SQL Server database but after entering one record it shows error on primary key. I am using `uniqueidentifier` as a primary key column. Kindly suggest how to resolve this error. I am using SQL Server 2012 and the table's name is `tbladdress`.

Error is

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Address_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object tblAddress. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblAddress] 
(
    [AddressID]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Username]    VARCHAR(50)      NOT NULL,
    [UserId]      BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [mobile]      VARCHAR(20)      NOT NULL,
    [Country]     VARCHAR(50)      NULL,
    [State]       VARCHAR(200)     NULL,
    [City]        VARCHAR(200)     NULL,
    [pincode]     VARCHAR(10)      NULL,
    [FullAddress] VARCHAR(300)     NULL,
    [landmark]    VARCHAR(150)     NULL,
    [Isactive]    BIT              NULL,
    [cdate]       DATE             NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Address_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What else can we tell you???  The error is already very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the error, it seems like you are trying to manually insert the record. Use `NEWID()` instead.

```
insert into tblAddress  (AddressID, Username, UserId, mobile)
values
(NEWID(),'John Cole',123456,'555555')
,(NEWID(),'John Anderson',65465465,'555444')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dcd26/7/0)**